# Remote port forwarding failed using freeSSHD + PuTTY

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, putty, freesshd

**Background:**

I have 2 machines, A is a server, and B is a local machine behind the firewall.
B has a SQL Server hosted at port 1433.
Now I want to access the SQL Server from A.

**Steps:**

1. Set up a freeSSHd on A.
2. Install PuTTY on B, set a remote port forwarding role `R8080->localhost:1433`.
3. Connect to A and the connection has been established.

Putty config:

[image]

**Error:**

When I tried to login SQL Server 127.0.0.1:8080 from A, putty on B reported an error `Received SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST for nonexistent channel 0`, session disconnected.

PS: When I uncheck the putty option `Remote ports do the same`, the port 8080 is not open on A. Why?

Attached truncated PuTTY log:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2016.05.19 16:46:58 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Event Log: Writing new session log (SSH raw data mode) to file: putty.log
Event Log: Looking up host "172.31.212.143"
Event Log: Connecting to 172.31.212.143 port 22
Event Log: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.67
Incoming raw data at 2016-05-19 16:46:58
  00000000  53 53 48 2d 32 2e 30 2d 57 65 4f 6e 6c 79 44 6f  SSH-2.0-WeOnlyDo
  00000010  20 32 2e 34 2e 33 0d 0a                           2.4.3..
Event Log: Server version: SSH-2.0-WeOnlyDo 2.4.3
Event Log: Using SSH protocol version 2
Event Log: Received remote port 0.0.0.0:9000 open request from 127.0.0.1:63600
Outgoing packet #0xe, type 92 / 0x5c (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_FAILURE)
  00000000  00 00 00 04 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 1d 52 65 6d 6f  ............Remo
  00000010  74 65 20 70 6f 72 74 20 69 73 20 6e 6f 74 20 72  te port is not r
  00000020  65 63 6f 67 6e 69 73 65 64 00 00 00 02 65 6e     ecognised....en
Outgoing raw data at 2016-05-19 16:47:06
  00000000  29 85 f8 78 fb 73 c0 ed 6f da e3 b6 79 66 a4 21  )..x.s..o...yf.!
  00000010  d8 8e b8 cc 5f cc e8 ca 7b df 9c 29 5f d7 dc 97  ...._...{..)_...
  00000020  a8 2f 3e ca ac ba 3b 9e 6b c3 a0 b1 e7 5b fb 63  ./>...;.k....[.c
  00000030  f0 fe c9 df ba 25 4d b6 ab f5 f8 d1 cc 7c 82 c1  .....%M......|..
  00000040  c5 d7 99 b7 79 b2 ce ea 15 db 14 35 ab ed 32 1f  ....y......5..2.
  00000050  04 a3 d9 a7 65 f2 be e6 33 5b c7 de 36 3f 2a 13  ....e...3[..6?*.
Event Log: Rejected channel open: Remote port is not recognised
Incoming raw data at 2016-05-19 16:47:16
  00000000  06 ca b4 ff 8b 1b dd c2 a1 e0 ce 29 f4 e2 fd 44  ...........)...D
  00000010  cf 53 63 75 88 88 0a 2c 22 19 39 6e 20 40 1d 46  .Scu...,".9n @.F
  00000020  0d c7 37 fa c3 74 f8 87 24 dc 21 19 1b 73 01 69  ..7..t..$.!..s.i
  00000030  ed c5 88 e3 5a 26 03 3a 79 41 7c 77 fa 57 64 4f  ....Z&.:yA|w.WdO
  00000040  29 9a 45 8e 9c e0 d3 ed b8 29 d1 b3 82 cf 42 dd  ).E......)....B.
Incoming packet #0x10, type 98 / 0x62 (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST)
  00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 65 78 69 74 2d 73 74 61  ........exit-sta
  00000010  74 75 73 00 00 00 00 00                          tus.....
Outgoing packet #0xf, type 1 / 0x01 (SSH2_MSG_DISCONNECT)
  00000000  00 00 00 02 00 00 00 3b 52 65 63 65 69 76 65 64  .......;Received
  00000010  20 53 53 48 32 5f 4d 53 47 5f 43 48 41 4e 4e 45   SSH2_MSG_CHANNE
  00000020  4c 5f 52 45 51 55 45 53 54 20 66 6f 72 20 6e 6f  L_REQUEST for no
  00000030  6e 65 78 69 73 74 65 6e 74 20 63 68 61 6e 6e 65  nexistent channe
  00000040  6c 20 30 00 00 00 02 65 6e                       l 0....en
Outgoing raw data at 2016-05-19 16:47:16
  00000000  b5 07 2f 6d 86 d7 72 6c 7c 21 8e fb de 3a 67 3d  ../m..rl|!...:g=
  00000010  64 cb dd bf e1 26 cd 44 db da 46 7c d6 f5 e5 1d  d....&.D..F|....
  00000020  35 54 1f 6d 0e c3 dd bb 8b d8 7e fe 2c 45 25 44  5T.m......~.,E%D
  00000030  6c 87 8f 25 da ee 93 6f 50 99 d4 15 84 ca 66 e5  l..%...oP.....f.
  00000040  87 dc 2b e4 45 2e b3 6c 1c d5 e1 0a 8f a4 c0 b2  ..+.E..l........
  00000050  33 d4 a0 d1 ca d4 4d 09 b5 56 04 ab c1 32 30 66  3.....M..V...20f
  00000060  44 19 09 6a 42 1e 77 d5 b1 c2 e6 5e ee 15 0d 7f  D..jB.w....^....
  00000070  a7 ef 74 02 12 1e 6e 6a dd 4c 8b 6f 29 71 7f 27  ..t...nj.L.o)q.'
Event Log: Disconnected: Received SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST for nonexistent channel 0
```

**Update:**

I think the issue is partially caused by freeSSHd, so I installed Bitvise SSH Server and tested again. This time A can open 8080 successfully and I accessed localhost:8080 from Chrome on A, the request packet successfuly reached at B, but still can NOT get the correct response. In short puTTY reports

> Rejected channel open: Remote port is not recognised.

Below is the updated PuTTY event log:

```
Event Log: Writing new session log (SSH raw data mode) to file: putty.log
Event Log: Looking up host "bartmaovm.cloudapp.net"
Event Log: Connecting to 13.90.250.178 port 22
Event Log: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.67
Incoming raw data at 2016-05-19 21:42:55
  00000000  53 53 48 2d 32 2e 30 2d 35 2e 33 39 20 46 6c 6f  SSH-2.0-5.39 Flo                              se..
Event Log: Server version: SSH-2.0-5.39 FlowSsh: Bitvise SSH Server (WinSSHD) 6.47: free only for personal non-commercial use
Event Log: Using SSH protocol version 2

Event Log: Received remote port 127.0.0.1:8080 open request from 127.0.0.1:50996
Outgoing packet #0xc, type 92 / 0x5c (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_FAILURE)
  00000000  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 1d 52 65 6d 6f  ............Remo
  00000010  74 65 20 70 6f 72 74 20 69 73 20 6e 6f 74 20 72  te port is not r
  00000020  65 63 6f 67 6e 69 73 65 64 00 00 00 02 65 6e     ecognised....en
Outgoing raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:12
  00000000  76 73 73 be 94 53 53 a4 32 28 0f 5f 56 57 26 14  vss..SS.2(._VW&.
  00000010  5b 20 04 33 b5 bd 6e c3 44 0f 42 56 bc 4f 8c 45  [ .3..n.D.BV.O.E
  00000020  57 04 d6 8d a7 42 5d c8 58 b6 c3 88 89 34 bf c9  W....B].X....4..
  00000030  1f 40 80 47 51 2b db d3 3e 6b 45 0e c4 ab 15 c1  .@.GQ+..>kE.....
  00000040  77 e2 96 8e ee 62 9e a5 27 0a c1 7f 4f 6c 31 ef  w....b..'...Ol1.
  00000050  d7 fc 4f c6 37 39 fc c9 95 0a df 3c 61 5a 03 d2  ..O.79.....<aZ..
Event Log: Rejected channel open: Remote port is not recognised
Incoming raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:13
  00000000  13 d3 0f fb e2 53 a9 29 a9 90 a5 2f b6 ef e5 b3  .....S.).../....
  00000010  c3 bb cb 07 ff fa d0 71 00 39 a8 24 6e f1 26 34  .......q.9.$n.&4
  00000020  b4 23 a6 76 6e d0 bc ae ea 67 8b 0b 45 0f 18 88  .#.vn....g..E...
  00000030  8a 3e 2a 73 a7 6f 68 3d c6 ca b5 88 78 5b ee 94  .>*s.oh=....x[..
  00000040  c1 72 21 ee 83 bf c5 25 eb db 47 e3 6a 58 a8 7f  .r!....%..G.jX..
  00000050  d0 db f9 8d 27 ae 9d 89 fa 62 6e 32 f3 53 a6 2f  ....'....bn2.S./
  00000060  0b 7d ec 32 cc 5d ab 3e 87 8d 38 18 9e d1 35 59  .}.2.].>..8...5Y
  00000070  ba e9 2f d9 e9 f4 dd dc e7 a2 c0 18 ae 1f 1f 11  ../.............
Incoming packet #0x10, type 90 / 0x5a (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN)
  00000000  00 00 00 0f 66 6f 72 77 61 72 64 65 64 2d 74 63  ....forwarded-tc
  00000010  70 69 70 00 00 00 02 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  pip.............
  00000020  00 00 09 31 32 37 2e 30 2e 30 2e 31 00 00 1f 90  ...127.0.0.1....
  00000030  00 00 00 09 31 32 37 2e 30 2e 30 2e 31 00 00 c7  ....127.0.0.1...
  00000040  35                                               5
Event Log: Received remote port 127.0.0.1:8080 open request from 127.0.0.1:50997
Outgoing packet #0xd, type 92 / 0x5c (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_FAILURE)
  00000000  00 00 00 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 1d 52 65 6d 6f  ............Remo
  00000010  74 65 20 70 6f 72 74 20 69 73 20 6e 6f 74 20 72  te port is not r
  00000020  65 63 6f 67 6e 69 73 65 64 00 00 00 02 65 6e     ecognised....en
Outgoing raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:13
  00000000  0e f7 90 71 a7 e2 0f b2 f0 3c a0 93 2b 69 bd 78  ...q.....<..+i.x
  00000010  16 16 bb 8f bb 60 10 44 09 e4 19 39 14 b3 9c 8a  .....`.D...9....
  00000020  42 17 02 95 bf 0c 14 19 63 43 da 3c de 54 1c 83  B.......cC.<.T..
  00000030  a3 98 79 54 9a 70 46 e3 b5 54 25 fd be af 18 5d  ..yT.pF..T%....]
  00000040  c5 48 fe 99 85 36 72 57 31 a9 05 99 91 17 8d 6e  .H...6rW1......n
  00000050  ab 63 1b 23 7e ec 06 30 b7 7a 62 13 2a 78 25 fc  .c.#~..0.zb.*x%.
Event Log: Rejected channel open: Remote port is not recognised
Incoming raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:13
  00000000  f1 fa 2e 26 9e b9 28 b4 cf ca 25 24 94 aa b1 8b  ...&..(...%$....
  00000010  49 6e 0a a6 f6 3e 89 9c 33 de 21 08 49 e8 3a 75  In...>..3.!.I.:u
  00000020  36 2f cb 7e a7 14 58 95 b5 69 e6 1b e7 ef 37 01  6/.~..X..i....7.
  00000030  4b a7 a6 79 14 83 c9 19 89 97 d1 01 95 e6 f6 a6  K..y............
  00000040  3e 44 6c 9d 94 c7 da ec 90 26 fd a9 1d 7d 5e bc  >Dl......&...}^.
  00000050  e8 3c a6 98 d3 ac 60 7c f7 e4 ea bf 2f be ff b2  .<....`|..../...
  00000060  ce d3 f6 c1 60 0c 54 07 0b 49 1f 65 a2 03 ad 44  ....`.T..I.e...D
  00000070  c5 18 cd c8 97 af 95 0e d0 67 de 6a 75 60 42 68  .........g.ju`Bh
Incoming packet #0x11, type 90 / 0x5a (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN)
  00000000  00 00 00 0f 66 6f 72 77 61 72 64 65 64 2d 74 63  ....forwarded-tc
  00000010  70 69 70 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  pip.............
  00000020  00 00 09 31 32 37 2e 30 2e 30 2e 31 00 00 1f 90  ...127.0.0.1....
  00000030  00 00 00 09 31 32 37 2e 30 2e 30 2e 31 00 00 c7  ....127.0.0.1...
  00000040  36                                               6
Event Log: Received remote port 127.0.0.1:8080 open request from 127.0.0.1:50998
Outgoing packet #0xe, type 92 / 0x5c (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_FAILURE)
  00000000  00 00 00 03 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 1d 52 65 6d 6f  ............Remo
  00000010  74 65 20 70 6f 72 74 20 69 73 20 6e 6f 74 20 72  te port is not r
  00000020  65 63 6f 67 6e 69 73 65 64 00 00 00 02 65 6e     ecognised....en
Outgoing raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:13
  00000000  41 f6 61 4c fa f9 4b f8 a4 59 80 df 24 79 74 1e  A.aL..K..Y..$yt.
  00000010  17 58 9c 72 93 c0 7a 37 b6 14 c8 d0 6e 65 7c cd  .X.r..z7....ne|.
  00000020  50 dd ea f8 1b 5b 39 32 d5 70 6d 41 72 a9 a3 76  P....[92.pmAr..v
  00000030  e3 51 b7 7e 17 15 62 e5 7e d5 18 12 53 70 58 23  .Q.~..b.~...SpX#
  00000040  c7 c9 60 7d 8b 9a 4c 46 ac f2 ec 3a 21 f7 37 16  ..`}..LF...:!.7.
  00000050  94 1a e5 d6 b8 a1 c4 4f 47 d7 af ec 2c 7a 47 ab  .......OG...,zG.
Event Log: Rejected channel open: Remote port is not recognised
Outgoing packet #0xf, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
  00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 65                       ........e
Outgoing raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:17
  00000000  32 d4 02 5d ea 07 ff ea 4b 8c 44 48 48 37 a0 da  2..]....K.DHH7..
  00000010  7b 37 a9 2c 7c ed 17 77 3e 17 f2 8e bb 62 da ae  {7.,|..w>....b..
  00000020  7f 93 b5 bb 57 f2 0d d3 a0 83 3b 75 60 a6 29 d6  ....W.....;u`.).
  00000030  e1 c7 5f 3c 67 ad a6 6c 4e 95 83 5c ef 1a 3f 39  .._<g..lN..\..?9
Outgoing packet #0x10, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
  00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 78                       ........x
Outgoing raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:17
  00000000  b2 c6 e8 6e 8c 95 e3 c6 8f dc 5e 12 d4 59 e5 e1  ...n......^..Y..
  00000010  8a 57 5d 25 47 da 4b c5 96 ba 2a f8 61 35 91 6c  .W]%G.K...*.a5.l
  00000020  a2 cd 49 74 6f a4 1b c6 f7 1a 09 77 5c b2 81 d6  ..Ito......w\...
  00000030  ae 0f 6d 63 e5 b5 93 67 16 64 dd e9 ff ba 01 df  ..mc...g.d......
Incoming raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:17
  00000000  7f ba 2f bc ad f4 0f e5 ec 27 d8 dd e4 03 39 31  ../......'....91
  00000010  71 10 e5 71 35 21 42 f9 1a ae 93 7b 56 42 1f 2c  q..q5!B....{VB.,
  00000020  16 8e 76 f9 89 24 db e6 eb fc ff a8 76 07 83 d9  ..v..$......v...
  00000030  a0 2f e4 02 fa 48 5f 8d 6a 7b 53 56 17 1b b7 a1  ./...H_.j{SV....
  00000040  7e c6 fe 66 42 2e 82 ce 36 21 46 e4 7c b3 c1 50  ~..fB...6!F.|..P
  00000050  bd 64 0e 36 7a 62 3a 4a 55 b6 a2 c4 c6 20 6e 40  .d.6zb:JU.... n@
  00000060  c7 36 55 db d8 cf 90 11 88 31 cd fe 3f e3 09 fd  .6U......1..?...
  00000070  51 9c 85 97 c8 cf 32 ce 58 57 dd 11 64 d1 2d a1  Q.....2.XW..d.-.
Incoming packet #0x12, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
  00000000  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 01 65                       ........e
Outgoing packet #0x11, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
  00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 69                       ........i
Outgoing raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:17
  00000000  54 d3 a3 a3 2b 9e cd d1 98 40 32 5e b2 ce f2 0a  T...+....@2^....
  00000010  ec fe bb af 0c 87 99 ae 4d e8 2c 08 e6 4e 2a 12  ........M.,..N*.
  00000020  88 7b 89 6a 72 62 da d8 85 81 49 39 66 12 54 ad  .{.jrb....I9f.T.
  00000030  8e ce 69 ed e9 a2 0b 7f 98 b2 b9 fc 4b 67 5f b7  ..i.........Kg_.
Outgoing packet #0x12, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
  00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 74                       ........t
Outgoing raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:17
  00000000  d4 4e 23 2f d9 c3 54 71 8e 21 2d cc d9 10 5e 4a  .N#/..Tq.!-...^J
  00000010  11 30 c7 2e f2 9e 9e 2d 33 c7 45 a2 cf a4 98 06  .0.....-3.E.....
  00000020  b3 27 68 61 3d cc 2d 00 ef bb b6 49 62 c5 e1 80  .'ha=.-....Ib...
  00000030  eb a5 ed 7d 35 73 44 6b 15 89 a8 1d 75 15 36 93  ...}5sDk....u.6.
Incoming raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:17
  00000000  bc a7 4c 8d 80 ce 51 8b 0a 55 0b f7 9b 70 e7 2f  ..L...Q..U...p./
  00000010  94 14 e1 46 d4 18 1d 8f 17 a6 1b 23 80 2d 11 ee  ...F.......#.-..
  00000020  3a b8 a2 1b 53 ef 50 94 19 53 2d d8 92 c8 24 7d  :...S.P..S-...$}
  00000030  de c9 43 db 22 b4 df 79 97 9f 60 21 b9 02 d1 09  ..C."..y..`!....
  00000040  42 10 19 7a 85 93 bd da 9a 9a ec ee 48 b3 a9 03  B..z........H...
  00000050  1e 52 74 c3 80 2f 9a 95 bb e9 0a bc b4 47 45 d9  .Rt../.......GE.
  00000060  cb 91 e8 1b 35 23 59 e6 40 64 1a af da 65 4a 7a  ....5#Y.@d...eJz
  00000070  05 6d d7 f1 0d ae eb aa 1b 1d ea d5 65 e4 06 35  .m..........e..5
Incoming packet #0x13, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
  00000000  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 01 78                       ........x
Incoming raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:17
  00000000  79 db b2 34 0d d5 25 35 eb db 04 a2 68 de da 47  y..4..%5....h..G
  00000010  f0 68 30 40 f1 1b c8 b6 71 9e 92 17 81 ab b9 ff  .h0@....q.......
  00000020  19 e3 aa 07 c5 e8 3c ff c7 31 65 e4 06 30 f4 f8  ......<..1e..0..
  00000030  5d 1f f6 8c a1 2c 81 48 8d 70 31 d1 5c 6b d2 00  ]....,.H.p1.\k..
  00000040  01 6a 97 af 43 00 05 d3 78 15 e7 e5 ee b4 d5 9e  .j..C...x.......
  00000050  4b e9 2f b2 ec 02 fa ac 63 42 4e 75 1e b6 e2 16  K./.....cBNu....
  00000060  5e 54 7c 48 9d b0 98 7d aa 3c b7 d2 20 38 e8 c5  ^T|H...}.<.. 8..
  00000070  e0 a4 b8 95 b0 b1 2a 7a 4e f3 20 77 d1 60 f4 db  ......*zN. w.`..
Incoming packet #0x14, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
  00000000  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 01 69                       ........i
Outgoing packet #0x13, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
  00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 0d                       .........
Outgoing raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:17
  00000000  9c 94 b6 76 81 c8 9e d3 bb 5d 5b 4e 89 4b e3 65  ...v.....][N.K.e
  00000010  89 e0 49 87 68 68 0e d6 28 47 a1 a3 bc af bc b1  ..I.hh..(G......
  00000020  8d 97 d2 e2 3b 4f 91 68 92 52 f6 9a 15 14 0e b1  ....;O.h.R......
  00000030  04 6b 19 bf 71 c9 98 b0 53 31 bf 10 a8 ff b4 01  .k..q...S1......
Incoming raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:18
  00000000  5e d7 6e f4 9d cb 9b d0 e8 72 15 57 cf ad 85 08  ^.n......r.W....
  00000010  8b c7 2d 39 ca d0 0c 47 71 1a ea a3 24 88 d6 75  ..-9...Gq...$..u
  00000020  95 5c 4c 34 1c 7e dc a4 42 9c 41 e3 c8 0a df 32  .\L4.~..B.A....2
  00000030  b6 ce d0 52 d9 66 7e 62 72 58 76 2c 70 ec 29 22  ...R.f~brXv,p.)"
  00000040  c2 e0 0c 32 f2 f1 c5 36 11 57 c7 8d 43 01 e2 50  ...2...6.W..C..P
  00000050  9e 74 a3 2e 8d 00 ff d2 a9 92 48 96 f8 fc c1 e2  .t........H.....
  00000060  01 c8 51 91 22 eb 06 32 fd aa 48 2d d8 8a 50 04  ..Q."..2..H-..P.
  00000070  83 2f d5 ce 13 05 da 8c af 1b c8 47 cc 72 dc b0  ./.........G.r..
Incoming packet #0x15, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
  00000000  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 01 74                       ........t
Incoming raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:19
  00000000  43 0f db ad 0b 66 14 e8 4b f9 16 3f 48 5b cb ad  C....f..K..?H[..
  00000010  b3 d8 a4 73 b2 34 fa d6 d9 9e 87 5e ed 81 d4 33  ...s.4.....^...3
  00000020  c2 a9 45 3c c1 91 5a 3c ad 05 0d 58 63 9b 10 27  ..E<..Z<...Xc..'
  00000030  49 bc 20 69 89 64 20 34 45 da 19 a2 17 80 05 ff  I. i.d 4E.......
  00000040  b9 7a 9b b1 8f f6 38 19 f9 23 32 df 0f e2 16 96  .z....8..#2.....
  00000050  45 81 b5 59 24 14 48 9c e8 b5 ca 42 a1 ef 42 a0  E..Y$.H....B..B.
  00000060  17 08 16 ad 76 46 5b 7b 0a e1 14 13 83 bb f0 28  ....vF[{.......(
  00000070  4e 3a e6 32 e9 d6 0a b0 86 fe b3 11 4b 88 55 ca  N:.2........K.U.
  00000080  c9 cc b3 f1 f4 39 9a d5 55 2d 54 c4 35 f6 80 9c  .....9..U-T.5...
  00000090  8e ac 1e 51 6f 2f 98 7b b6 9d d1 ae a0 06 ec 02  ...Qo/.{........
  000000a0  b1 a3 42 a8 dd 30 9f 09 2f 66 01 8e aa 3e 45 57  ..B..0../f...>EW
  000000b0  07 89 55 30 d3 e3 0d b3 f3 8a 93 c5 62 ee 6e 40  ..U0........b.n@
  000000c0  eb 1a 8d 2a f2 28 e7 34 d7 6a 1e b0 9a 0e b4 35  ...*.(.4.j.....5
  000000d0  3d 2d 08 20 c9 6f c8 bb e3 44 a6 49 ff 16 48 b3  =-. .o...D.I..H.
  000000e0  8d 59 d8 6c e3 90 03 bc 72 46 86 a0 29 d6 72 83  .Y.l....rF..).r.
  000000f0  40 94 a0 06 bf 5c 05 a1 35 9d 7a 63 82 3d 7f 50  @....\..5.zc.=.P
  00000100  14 ee ff ae c9 eb 0d 67 98 3f 68 33 1a a9 94 3a  .......g.?h3...:
  00000110  f1 8b cd 65 59 35 85 4e 49 6a 40 f2 e8 1c 98 2b  ...eY5.NIj@....+
  00000120  0d c1 7d 88 c3 64 dc 8d ff 34 90 2a f9 23 ee d3  ..}..d...4.*.#..
  00000130  60 a2 8d 3c 98 48 12 a3 0a 79 70 b6 c3 ba 6c 3e  `..<.H...yp...l>
  00000140  f7 60 e2 0a 87 5f f8 46 11 00 fc 51 f0 52 42 aa  .`..._.F...Q.RB.
  00000150  ab f1 57 15 74 64 28 18 2f 15 47 1a 97 f8 2c c4  ..W.td(./.G...,.
  00000160  e8 ad 87 8c 97 aa 97 64 a0 dc fe 0a 85 16 cb ab  .......d........
  00000170  b4 c6 14 7b 23 d8 34 fb ed e0 86 85 63 1e ab 50  ...{#.4.....c..P
  00000180  91 7f 2f 9f 80 ba ba 50 a8 fa 42 bf 4a 6e b1 db  ../....P..B.Jn..
  00000190  bc be 81 e3 71 d2 f4 37 75 c7 62 bf b2 02 0a de  ....q..7u.b.....
  000001a0  14 f1 d9 0a 28 f3 63 1f ca 41 96 bb c1 5d 54 4e  ....(.c..A...]TN
  000001b0  c7 c3 66 ee ec 32 9a c8 cd 5f e6 d3 80 66 06 c5  ..f..2..._...f..
  000001c0  f7 5d 22 ad 03 21 88 f7 4a b0 6b f5 02 50 16 f0  .]"..!..J.k..P..
  000001d0  58 1a c2 2f b9 ca 89 42 6a d6 3a 5d 29 39 77 04  X../...Bj.:])9w.
  000001e0  71 95 81 12 0d 39 15 1e 80 34 67 5f bf 4f c7 57  q....9...4g_.O.W
  000001f0  a5 9c ec 7b d4 40 08 79 e4 ed 09 44 24 e8 83 5c  ...{.@.y...D$..\
Incoming packet #0x16, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
  00000000  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 38 1b 5d 32 3b 43 6f 6d 6d  .......8.]2;Comm
  00000010  61 6e 64 20 50 72 6f 6d 70 74 20 2d 20 65 78 69  and Prompt - exi
  00000020  74 07 1b 5d 32 3b 43 6f 6d 6d 61 6e 64 20 50 72  t..]2;Command Pr
  00000030  6f 6d 70 74 07 1b 5b 35 3b 31 48 1b 5b 3f 37 68  ompt..[5;1H.[?7h
Incoming packet #0x17, type 98 / 0x62 (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST)
  00000000  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 0b 65 78 69 74 2d 73 74 61  ........exit-sta
  00000010  74 75 73 00 00 00 00 00                          tus.....
Event Log: Server sent command exit status 0
Incoming packet #0x18, type 96 / 0x60 (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF)
  00000000  00 00 01 00                                      ....
Outgoing packet #0x14, type 96 / 0x60 (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF)
  00000000  00 00 00 00                                      ....
Outgoing raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:19
  00000000  d7 56 6c 68 4b b7 f3 69 c8 42 75 83 af 00 18 ae  .VlhK..i.Bu.....
  00000010  d7 1f 76 20 a7 a6 8f af 87 6f 6b 2d 65 81 c2 7f  ..v .....ok-e...
  00000020  42 23 ee 00 e8 9e 01 4e 4b ce 02 b8 f3 a6 ca 34  B#.....NK......4
Outgoing packet #0x15, type 97 / 0x61 (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE)
  00000000  00 00 00 00                                      ....
Outgoing raw data at 2016-05-19 21:43:19
  00000000  50 68 8d 8f 8d d6 61 cf d1 65 a4 a4 b4 55 60 9c  Ph....a..e...U`.
  00000010  d0 e3 86 36 d7 ae bf 8c 17 dd 75 1e d2 4b ee e7  ...6......u..K..
  00000020  95 b9 60 ee 24 e2 13 2f e8 3f 41 d2 48 cc ab 4d  ..`.$../.?A.H..M
Incoming packet #0x19, type 97 / 0x61 (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE)
  00000000  00 00 01 00                                      ....
Event Log: Disconnected: All channels closed
```

Comment: Show us an event log from PuTTY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log shows that you have configured port forwarding from port 9000 (contrary to your post) from any host.

When you try to connect to the port 9000 on the server, the server sends the "port-forwarded channel" request to the PuTTY for source host "0.0.0.0". The PuTTY obviously gets confused by the "0.0.0.0" (probably expecting an empty string instead) and rejects the request.

I cannot say, who's wrong, if PuTTY or freeSSHd. But they are obviously not compatible with each other.

I'd definitely try a different SSH server. The freeSSHd does not have a good reputation.

[Bitvise SSH server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) is good and has a free version for personal use.

---

You may also try to use "0.0.0.0:9000" as the source port to match what the server provides, but I doubt it would work.

Comment: I tried '0.0.0.0', not working. So use Bitvise server instead and another issue occurred. I've updated the question, please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Exceed the max input count:( I've connected two different Bitvise server A & A1, and showed different errors. logs are [PuTTY_A](http://bartmaovm.cloudapp.net/putty-A.txt) and [PuTTY_A1](http://bartmaovm.cloudapp.net/putty-A1.txt). please ignore freeSSHd test log since I've given up using it.

Comment: Please ignore log of connecting to server A1, it's caused by forgetting granting user port forwarding access.

Comment: any idea? I need your help:)

Comment: I already granted the virtual account the port forwarding access:(

Comment: I attach the BitVise log [here](http://bartmaovm.cloudapp.net/bitviselog.txt)

Comment: OK, [BitviseSrv](http://bartmaovm.cloudapp.net/BvSshServe-Session1.txt) and [Putty](http://bartmaovm.cloudapp.net/Putty-Session1.txt)

Comment: I had the same problem. But if I set the source port to `127.0.0.1:8080`, it works.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Mine is working after adding `127.0.0.1`! It's weird but anyway kinda a workaround.